# sql query to accept wild card characters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My requirement is to accept the wild card characters and display the records. 
Below is the wildcard characters condition:

**% = 0 to many characters**

**_ = 1 character**

Below is my SQL query:

labelSerialNumber and productSerialNumber will accept wild card characters(% and _) and should display the records accordingly.

```
where (:productSerialNumber is null or
    pd_res.product_serial_number =
    :productSerialNumber) like '%_%'
and (:labelSerialNumber is null or
    pd_res.label_serial_number = :labelSerialNumber)
and ('nullValue' = :formatDescFlag or
    TRIM(lf.format_id_desc) in (:formatDesc))   
and (:formatId is null or
    lf.format_id = :formatId)        
and (:fromDate is null or
    pd_res.created_timestamp >=
    to_date(:fromDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
and (:todate is null or
    pd_res.created_timestamp <
    (to_date(:todate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1))) ProductData_inner) ProductData)
```

Please suggest what modifications to be done for the above query to display the matching records when wild card characters are given for productSerial number/labelSerialNumber. Thanks.

**--EDIT1--**

I want the above query to accept wild card characters (%, _) for productSerialNumber/labelSerialNumberhave . I added LIKE operator in the WHERE clause of the above query for productSerialNumber to accept wildcard characters as shown below:

```
 where (:productSerialNumber is null or
                                       pd_res.product_serial_number =
                                       :productSerialNumber) like '%_%'
```

It's throwing SQL exception as right parenthesis missing when I ran the above query after LIKE operator is added. Please suggest.

**--EDIT2--**

productSerialNumber and labelSerialNumber are two different textboxes in UI where user can enter the values and search for the results.
They are not mandatory fields.User can enter just productSerialNumber which will accept wild card characters(for ex: %667_%) or just labelSerialNumber which will accept wildcard chacters or user can enter both the fields depends on his search criteria.

Can i modify the condition as below:

```
where ( (:productSerialNumber is null or
         pd_res.product_serial_number = :productSerialNumber)
       like '%_%'
       )
and ((:labelSerialNumber is null or 
      pd_res.label_serial_number = :labelSerialNumber)
      like '%_%')
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by " the output was not as expected".  Give us some sample raw data, the output you got for a given parameter and the output you wanted.  The more details you provide the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.  Also, did you really mean to tag this question [oracle] *and* [sql-server] ?

Comment: Also, it looks like you truncated your query when you posted it here

Comment: @APC , when i used like keyword to accept wild card characters inside CASE it was showing Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'. and its only oracle i need to tag. Thanks

Comment: @APC , Please see the edited post, added full query. Please suggest how can i modify the above query to accept wild card characters (%, _) for productSerialNumber/labelSerialNumber. Thanks.

Comment: You in the same class?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322380/sql-query-to-accept-wild-card-characters-and-display-the-records-accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to ignore the full horror of this code and focus on the bit you say is throwing an exception.

We cannot specify compound conditions like this:

```
where (:productSerialNumber is null or
           pd_res.engine_serial_number =
                   :productSerialNumber) like '%_%'
```

We need to join them with boolean operators:

```
where ( (:productSerialNumber is null or
         pd_res.engine_serial_number = :productSerialNumber)
       and coalesce(:productSerialNumber, pd_res.engine_serial_number )  like '%_%'
       )
```

Note that `like '%_%'` is equivalent to `is not null`.  If you want to explicitly test that the serial number contains an underscore then this test would be better:

```
instr(coalesce(:productSerialNumber, pd_res.engine_serial_number ), '_') > 0
```

Although having read this comment ...

> "how can i modify the above query to accept wild card characters (%, _) for 
>   productSerialNumber/labelSerialNumber"

... it seems that what you want is actually

```
 pd_res.engine_serial_number like
                 coalesce(:productSerialNumber, pd_res.engine_serial_number )
```

With this formulation, if the bind variable `:productSerialNumber` is null the comparison collapses to `pd_res.engine_serial_number like pd_res.engine_serial_number`, which is always true; if `:productSerialNumber` is populated with an exact value it will resolve to `:productSerialNumber=pd_res.engine_serial_number`; if `:productSerialNumber` is populated with a partial value and wildcards  it will resolve to `:productSerialNumber like pd_res.engine_serial_number`.

By all means use the same technique for testing `:labelSerialNumber` and any other parameter which takes your fancy.

Comment: Thanks,  please see --EDIT2-- in my post above, will that work?  prodctSerialNumber and labelSerialNumber are two different independent columns getting input from frontend.

Comment: Your EDIT2 is just a version of EDIT1, which I have already said won't work the way you want it to.